# Why is a pointer to a pointer incompatible with a pointer to an array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

OK, I'm having trouble understanding pointers to pointers vs pointers to arrays.
Consider the following code:

```
char s[] = "Hello, World";
char (*p1)[] = &s;
char **p2 = &s;
printf("%c\n", **p1); /* Works */
printf("%c\n", **p2); /* Segmentation fault */
```

Why does the first printf work, while the second one doesn't?

From what I understand, 's' is a pointer to the first element of the array (that is, 'H').
So declaring p2 as char** means that it is a pointer to a pointer to a char. Making it point to 's' should be legal, since 's' is a pointer to a char. And thus dereferencing it (i.e. **p2) should give 'H'. But it doesn't!

Comment: None of the assignments compile on VC++2010.

Comment: Strange. It works fine on GCC 4.4.4.

Comment: @Meta : Not on GCC 4.3.4 ([demo](http://ideone.com/K6D1D)) or 4.5.1 ([demo](http://ideone.com/gTGhY))...

Comment: @Meta : Ah, your code is valid C but not valid C++; the `c++` tag was throwing everyone off, so I removed it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your misunderstand lies in what `s` is.  It is *not* a pointer: it is an array.

Now in most contexts, `s` evaluates to a pointer to the first element of the array: equivalent to `&s[0]`, a pointer to that `'H'`.   The important thing here though is that that pointer value you get when evaluating `s` is a temporary, ephemeral value - just like `&s[0]`.

Because that pointer isn't a permanent object (it's not actually what's stored in `s`), you can't make a pointer-to-pointer point at it.  To use a pointer-to-pointer, you must have a real pointer object to point to - for example, the following is OK:

```
char *p = s;
char **p2 = &p;
```

If you evaluate `*p2`, you're telling the compiler to load the thing that `p2` points to and treat it as a pointer-to-char.  That's fine when `p2` does actually point at a pointer-to-char; but when you do `char **p2 = &s;`, the thing that `p2` points to isn't a pointer at all - it's an array (in this case, it's a block of 13 `char`s).

Comment: Ah OK. I think I'm starting to understand now.
Can you just clear up the part about s being a 'temporary, ephemeral value'? Wouldn't it be the same address everytime?

Comment: @Meta: I mean that the pointer that `s` evaluates to is not an addressable object, in the same way that `a + 1` is not (in standardese, it's not an lvalue).

Comment: @caf, if `s` is not an addressable object, how come `&s` is not a compile error (but `&(a+1)` is)?

Comment: @Shahbaz: `s` *is* an addressable object - it's an array - but the pointer value that `s` evaluates to *in most contexts* is not an addressable object.  It so happens that `&s` is one of the contexts where `s` does *not* evaluate to a pointer to the first element - it remains a designator for the array, so `&s` gives the address of that array.  The other context where `s` still designates the array itself is `sizeof s` (so this gives the size of the *array*, not of a pointer).

Comment: @caf, it is starting to make sense. Array name is like a function name, `&` of it gives its address, but since without `&` it doesn't make sense, without `&` it also gives the address! The same way `func` and `&func` would be the same value. That is also why `char (*p)[]` should be used, similar to `char (*fptr)()`. Am I correct?

Comment: @Shahbaz: It's very similar to the situation with functions, but not identical.  The difference is that a function designator like `func` evaluates to a pointer to the function, which has the same type and value as `&func`.  In the case of arrays, an array name like `s` evaluates to a pointer to *the first element* of the array, whereas `&s` is a pointer *to the array*.  Now the first element of the array is necessarily located at the start of the array, so `s` and `&s` have the same value (eg. when converted to `void *`), but they have different *types*.

Answer (score 2):

`From what I understand, 's' is a pointer to the first element of the array`
No, s is an array.  It can be reduced to a pointer to an array, but until such time, it is an array.  A pointer to an array becomes a pointer to the first element of the array.  (yeah, it's kinda confusing.)

`char (*p1)[] = &s;`
This is allowed, it's a pointer to an array, assigned the address of an array.  It points to the first element of s.

`char **p2 = &s;`
That makes a pointer to a pointer and assigns it the address of the array.  You assign it a pointer to the first element of s (a `char`), when it thinks it's a pointer to a pointer to one or more chars.  Dereferencing this is undefined behavior. (segfault in your case)

The proof that they are different lies in `sizeof(char[1000])` (returns size of 1000 chars, not the size of a pointer), and functions like this:

```
template<int length>
void function(char (&arr)[length]) {}
```

which will compile when given an array, but not a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the sample that works, plus printouts of pointer addresses to make things simple to see:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char s[] = "Hello, World";
char (*p1)[] = &s;
char *p2 = (char*)&s;

int main(void)
{
   printf("%x %x %x\n", s, p2, *p2);
   printf("%x\n", &s);    // Note that `s` and `&s` give the same value
   printf("%x\n", &s[0]);
   printf("%c\n", **p1); 
   printf("%c\n", *p2);
}
```

Comment: I added one line to your code that makes it a bit clearer why this happens.